# Is there a programmatic way to identify built-in applications?

Tags: macos, applications, homebrew, unix

I'm trying to keep an inventory of where each application in my Mac came from (context: I'm trying to be disciplined and install things only through the App Store, Homebrew or Caskroom).

Apps that came from the App Store can be identified because their application bundle contains a `_MASReceipt` directory. Is there a similar trick to identify the built-in applications? One idea is to check if `CFBundleIdentifier` in `Info.plist` starts with `com.apple`. Any others?

Comment: Nice idea! Why not go with the CFBundleIdentifier approach?

Comment: Look in /Library/Receipts